# Moving tenants but keeping API / Apps in current Azure AD

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

So I've done some research, but I just wanted to check in and see what others opinions are on a current situation that our employer is going through and get some guidance to add to the research that I already have.

So we currently have a Microsoft Tenant, with an Azure AD subscription with APIs and Apps. We plan on moving everything SharePoint related to this new tenant, but we are keeping the APIs and Apps in the current Azure AD - The new tenant has their own Azure AD.

Would it be possible to hook our API calls to the new tenant?
Could we grant permissions for our Apps and use them in the new tenant?

If anyone has any details about tenant migrations and such, please throw out any information that you have - Since all of that will be useful.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. But if you have a lot of apps, there will be a lot of work.

First of all, make sure all your api applications and app applications are [multi-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-registration-to-be-multi-tenant).

Secondly, you could use [Powershell cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadserviceprincipal?view=azurermps-6.13.0) `New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "{client id of your api application}"` to add the api application as the enterprise app into your new tenant.

Then you need to do [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin) for the apps (of the old tenant) against the new tenant.

I assume that your app is registered in tenant_x and want to add it into tenant_y.

You can redirect the user to the Microsoft identity platform admin consent endpoint.

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_y}/v2.0/adminconsent?
  client_id={client id of the app in tenant_x}
  &state=12345
  &redirect_uri={redirect_uri of the app in tenant_x}
  &scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

Use an admin account of tenant_y to log in to finish the admin consent.

Please note that for `scope` you cannot use `api://{client id of api app}/.default` because it will tell you that the api app doesn't exist in tenant_y.

Although we use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` for `scope`, it will also show the permission for api app when you do the admin consent. So don't worry about it.

After you finish it, the enterprise app of the app in tenant_x will appear in tenant_y, with all the api permissions.

Comment: Thanks so much @Allen, this is great help!