# Azure Multi tenant app - request admin consent for roles of own application

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I made a multi tenant app (client id: "abc-efg") that needs some resources of the Graph of my customer tenant. To get permission to their graph, I created an url that the Azure admin of my customer clicks and consents:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminConsent?client_id=abc-efg&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

If I added application permissions (i.e. Groups.Read) to the app with the client id "abc-efg" the customer gets a consent screen and can add the application to his tenant.
This works great!

I have another application now that exposes some own permissions (ie: Custom.Read.All). The app *exposes* those permissions and also *has* the permissions at the same time. This is wanted because the app is the only comsumer of the api that is protected with the custom permission.

My app needs those custom permissions from the customer now, so I try it the same way like I did with the graph:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminConsent?client_id=vwx-xyz&scope=api://vwx-xyz/.default
```

But this is throwing an error message:

> Application is requesting a token for itself. This scenario is
> supported only if resource is specified using the GUID based App
> Identifier.

So I try it with the GUID only:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminConsent?client_id=vwx-xyz&scope=vwx-xyz
```

But this app is not found, because the resource does not exist.

If I google this error message I find only comments for the old V1 endpoint, not for V2.

Anyone has an explanation for this? How can I get application permissions for my customer tenants for permissions defined by my own app?

In the end I want to be able to receive tokens with an issuer tenant id of my customer, but roles/scopes of my own app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request a token for yourself,you must create two applications, one as a client application and the other as an api application. You have to make sure that these two applications are multi-tenant applications, and then use the client application to call the api application.
 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis) Detailed official documents.

For multi-tenant applications, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755956/moving-tenants-but-keeping-api-apps-in-current-azure-ad/61773556#61773556) are more detailed answers for your reference.

**Update:**

After my test, if you want to use a single application, the steps are basically the same as the link I provided:

1. Use [Powershell cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadserviceprincipal?view=azureadps-2.0) `New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId  "{client id of your  application}"` to add the application as an enterprise application to your customer tenant.
2. Redirect the user to the Microsoft identity platform administrator consent endpoint, log in with your customer tenant's administrator account to complete the administrator consent.
3. As stated in the link, you cannot use `api://{client id of app}/.default` for `scope` because it will tell you that the  application does not exist in the customer tenant, and you need to use `https://graph. microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: Yes - this way I know, but I do not need two applications. It should be enough if my web application exposes & consumes the permissions. If I have two apps this highers the complexitiy and my client needs two register two client applications. Also in my id tokens I will not receive the API permissions anymore, so my client application will have to make another call to read those. In my case I have a good reason to prefer only a single application.

Comment: @DavidElsnerd   Yes, you can also use a single application, I made a modification in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds interesting. Does this mean I need powershell access to my customers tenant? I will not get this... I will only be able to send a link that their admin can consent to. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @DavidElsner   You must add the application to the customer tenant, otherwise the customer tenant will not be able to approve the administrator's consent for the application. If you do not have permission to use Powershell to access your customer tenant, you can let the customer add the application to the tenant by themselves. It is the easiest way.

Comment: @DavidElsner  Hi,If my answer is helpful to you, can you accept it as an answer?

Comment: I tried around - if the app is not installed at my customers tenant and if I send them a link to the consent endpoint they can consent and the app is added automatically to the enterprise applications. Are you sure its necessary to add the app before? That is still confusing for me now...